# if $G$ is finite group then polycyclic group is equivalent to super solvable group?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I don't know why this is true?
can you help me:

> if $G$ is finite group then polycyclic group is equivalent to super solvable group

**Definitions-**

### Polycyclic group

$G$ is a polycyclic if has a subnormal series s.t. all of factors are cyclic.

### Supersolvable

$G$ is a super solvable if has a normal series s.t. all of factors are cyclic.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Supersolvable groups are always polycyclic is clear, and note that for a finite group, being solvable is equivalent to being a Polycyclic group .

Comment: $A_4$ is polycyclic but nor supersolvable,so what you wrote is not true.

Answer (score -1):

Let $G$ be a finite polycyclic group then $G$ is solvable.

**Proof:** Let $1\leq N_1 \leq ... \leq N_k=G$ be the subnormal series.

Use induction on $k$,

for $k=1$, it is clear. Assume it is true for $k-1$. Then by assumption $N_{k-1}$ is supersolvable. As $G/N_{k-1}$ is cyclic then $G$ is solvable.

Thus, for finite groups two defination is equivalent.(Being solvable and being polycyclic.) (The othe case is obvious as mentioned in the comments)

Comment: No. Normal subgroup is not a transitive property. The alternating group on 4 symbols is polycyclic but not supersolvable.

Comment: Oh sorry, $N$ is supersolvable and $G/N$ is super solvable does not implies $G$ is super solvable. This is the wrong assumtion in my proof.

Comment: @ahulpke : Being subnormal  is a transitive , there is no problem in that step. I edited the answer. Thank you.

Comment: @mesel:Is it a counter example?we know that $A_4$is polycyclic but $A_4$ is not super solvable!and $A_4$ is finite

Comment: @parisa: After editing, I changed the statement. I claimed that "G is solvable". $A_4$ is solvable hence it is not a counter example.

Comment: @parisa: For finite groups, polycyclic groups are exactly solvable groups.